# Client implementation using the OPC Foundation ANSI C Stack

Tags: client, client-server, opc, opc-ua, ansi-c

Can anyone help me out to implement the **OPC UA client implementation** using the **OPC Foundation ANSI C** Stack. I believe that only the server implementation is available in the repository, so far.

I have the OPC UA server working using the OPC Foundation ANSI C stack and i'm using the GUI client to communicate to the server.

It would be great if anyone helps me out to implement a **simple client** using  the **OPC Foundation ANSI C** stack to connect to the server and do a **data access** (single variable) from the server's **address space**.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: tell us what have u tried so far. also be more specific when asking a question.

Comment: Do you mean the OPC Foundation ANSI C Stack or open62541? Please remove the open62541 label if your question is about the ANSI C Stack. Otherwise please rephrase so that it is clear which stack you are using.

Comment: @dwilliss I have rephrased the question. Can you have a look at it now?

Comment: @breakpoint I think the edit will now be more meaningful

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to complicate your life using the stack directly? use a SDK.

Here is an open source option that offers client and server options https://open62541.org/.  It comes with examples and good documentation.